# Python importing difference

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

In Python, it looks like custom classes, need to be fully classified when imported

For example,

```
from analytics.npv_differences import NpvDifferences
```

analytics
----npv_differences.py (contains the NpvDifferences class)

when the following will not work:

```
from analytics import NpvDifferences
```

However, for pandas, both the following work

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
```

why the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What's the difference?

The difference is made by an `__init__.py` file.

It is a file that turns a directory containing Python code into a Python *package*. Here's the [documenation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) on packages.

The `__init__.py` contains code that is run when the package is imported.
That includes:

- `import module`
- `import module.submodule`
- `from module import something`
- `from module.submodule import something`

In all of these cases the `module/__init__.py` is executed. You can test that by adding a `print()` call inside the file and observing the output during imports.

It can be empty, but most of the time it imports from subdirectories to allow the short importing form. Here's the said [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/__init__.py) file from `pandas` source. If you take a quick look, you'll see that there are imports from subpackages.

## How to do the same?

If you create an `__init__.py` file in your directory `analytics` and import the class there, you'll be able to use the short import like in `pandas`.

Your `analytics/__init__.py` file should contain something like that:

```
from analytics.npv_differences import NpvDifferences
```

The `analytics` part of the import can be omitted, turning it into a *relative import*. If you put this inside your `__init__.py`, you'll get the same outcome:

```
from .npv_differences import NpvDifferences
```

Relative imports are better in the sense that if you happen to rename your package to something else, your imports won't break.

## Why this works?

The reason why importing inside `__init__.py` allows for short imports is because *any variable defined in `__init__.py` is available at module level*.

For example, if `module/__init__.py` contains the following code:

```
from .submodule import SomeClass  # this defines a `SomeClass` variable
__doc__ = '''This behaviour is commonly used to define 
             module-level documentation, available with 
             a call `help(module)`.'''
config_var = 1337
```

then the following becomes possible:

```
import module
help(module)  # will output the content of the __doc__ variable
module.SomeClass()  # create an instance of module.submodule.SomeClass
print(module.config_var)  # prints 1337
```

That's why in the `pandas` `__init__.py` any unnecessary variables are carefully deleted with `del`. Make sure not to pollute the module-level namespace.

Comment: awesomeee. Why is importing in the __init__ file make the import accessible via short import? You mentioned that when the package is imported, the __init__ is executed. So when I import any class from that package, __init__ is executed? Also, once those imports are executed, they are available for the original file to import them? I'm confused where they are once __init__ is executed.

Comment: @Crt I've updated the post. Not sure I understand your last question though

Comment: thanks! You seem to still be referencing the class as module.SomeClass() even thought it was imported in the __init__. I thought it could be referenced just as SomeClass()

Comment: @Crt if you use `from module import SomeClass`, accessing `SomeClass()` will be possible

Comment: ah yes but, i thought because you're already importing it in the __init__ file, then it could just be referenced as SomeClass() rather than importing again.